# Checking if data is in a table row

Tags: php

This is my first post so please bear with me with inputting the code into here. Im trying to output some images to a PDF and need to create a if statement that looks for data with in a row.

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "testdb", "********")
    or die ("Unable to connect!");    

// select database  
mysql_select_db("testdb") or die ("Unable to select database!");      

// Select all the rows in the test table
$query = "SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE testid=89";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $image = $row[1]; 
    $text = $row[2];
}
```

That's what I have so far and basically I need something along the line of this:

```
If (data in row 1) {
    print $image;
} else {
    print $text;
}
```

Comment: what data does your table contain?

Comment: just text and image paths in-putted from a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what you're looking for since it isn't very clear, but I *think* what you're wanting to do is check to see if `$image` has a value, and if so, display it. If not, display `$text` instead.

If this is the case use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). It will tell you if a variable is empty or not.

```
if (!empty($image))
 {
   print $image;
 }
else
 {
  print $text;
 }
```

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: @user1573979, if this answer has solved your problem then you can click the green tick next to it to mark it as ["accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This indicates to the wider community that your question is solved and provides both you and the answerer with some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just need to test for data in $image

```
if(!empty($image))
{
    echo $image;
}
else
{
    echo $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you are using old `mysql_*` functions which are depreciated, you are almost there

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "testdb", "********") or die ("Unable to connect!");    
// select database  
 mysql_select_db("testdb") or die ("Unable to select database!");      
  // Select all the rows in the test table
    $query = "SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE testid=89";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
     die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
// This will only be called if there is a matching result.
{
 echo $row[1]; 
 echo $row[2];
}
```

Edit: Here is a cut and paste of a section of a query that happen to be open in eclipse:

```
$arrKPIData = Array();
try{
    $dbh = new PDO($this->mySQLAccessData->hostname, $this->mySQLAccessData->username, $this->mySQLAccessData->password);
    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
    $obj = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new kpiData);
    $dataCount=0;
    foreach($stmt as $kpiData)
    {
        $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['year']=$kpiData->year;
        $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['month']=$kpiData->month;
        $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['measure']=$kpiData->kpiMeasure;
        $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['var1']=$kpiData->var1;
        $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['var2']=$kpiData->var2;
        $dataCount++;
        unset($stmt);
    }
    unset($dbh);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Error : '.$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
unset($arrKPIData);
```

I am populating a simple array with data before I cleanse it and convert it into a class further in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !empty($row[1]) ) { 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isset to check variable.

Like

```
if(isset($images) !='')
{
echo $images;
}
```

Comment: $image = $row[1]; means it is always set UNLESS field defaults to NULL, you need to check for content

Comment: so if $image is '' (blank - no data) it doesn't show the text!

Comment: You've changed this to if(TRUE!=''). No matter how you change things ISSET will never give the right answer!